# Pin Change Interrupt - External Interrupt with Internal Interrupt

Tags: c, avr, interrupt-handling

Here in the program, am cycling through LEDs using timer interrupt & if someone presses a switch, it should stop the first interrupt & trigger second one that should lit the led according to the switch pressed. Here, am a little confused which interrupt is being called. I referred some books for Pin Change Interrupt & wrote a few lines for setting PCMSK2. The output am getting is "initially all leds are cycling, when a switch is pressed...cycling of leds stops & starts over again (which means that program is reading input, just not triggering the second interrupt). It doesn't stop or pause & doesn't lit subsequent led." Could anyone help, please?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#define PINK_MASK \
    ((1<<PINK0)|(1<<PINK1)|(1<<PINK2)|(1<<PINK3)|(1<<PINK4)|(1<<PINK5)|(1<<PINK6)|(1<<PINK7))


volatile unsigned int intrs, i=1;

void enable_ports(void);
void delay(void);

extern void __vector_23 (void) __attribute__ ((interrupt));

extern void __vector_25 (void) __attribute__ ((signal));

void enable_ports()
{
    DDRB = 0xff;   //PORTB as output for leds

    PORTB = 0xff;

    DDRK = 0x00;  //PORTK as input from switches

    PORTK |= PINK_MASK;

    PCMSK2 = PINK_MASK;     //ENABLE PCMSK2, Setting interrupts

    PCICR = 0x04;

    PCIFR = 0x04;

    TCCR0B = 0x03;      //Setting TIMER

    TIMSK0 = 0x01;

    TCNT0 = 0x00;

    intrs = 0;
}
void __vector_23 (void)
{
    intrs++;
    if(intrs > 60)
    {
        intrs = 0;
        PORTB = (0xff<<i);

        i++ ;
        if(i == 10 )
        {
            PORTB = 0xff;
            i = 1 ;
        }
    }
}

void __vector_25 (void)
{
    unsigned char switches;

    switches = ((~PINK) & (PINK_MASK)); //Reading from switches

    if(switches & (1<<PINK0))
        PORTB = (PORTB<<PINK0);

    else if (switches & (1<<PINK1))
        PORTB = (PORTB<<PINK1);

    else if (switches & (1<<PINK2))
        PORTB = (PORTB<<PINK2);

    else if (switches & (1<<PINK3))
        PORTB = (PORTB<<PINK3);

    else if (switches & (1<<PINK4))
        PORTB = (PORTB<<PINK4);

    else if (switches & (1<<PINK5))
        PORTB = (PORTB<<PINK5);

    else if (switches & (1<<PINK6))
        PORTB = (PORTB<<PINK6);

    else if (switches & (1<<PINK7))
        PORTB = (PORTB<<PINK7);
}

int main(void)
{
    enable_ports();
    sei();

    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks for all your support.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Atmel µCs. But maybe you could ask on http://embdev.net/

Comment: What specific device are you targeting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

External interrupts in the AVR architecture are confusing but not impossible. I found the best resource for me was the [AVR libc page on interrupts](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html). I think you've made the code too complicated for what you want it to do. Let's start from scratch:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void main() {
    sei();
    while(1) {};
}
```

AVR libc actually makes processing interrupts pretty painless. In the page I linked to above there's a list of all the supported interrupt vectors on each AVR chip. Let's assume you're using a Mega32 and you now want to have the LEDs blink using a timer interrupt. Let's add to the program:

```
uint8_t led_state;

ISR(TIMER0_COMP_vect) {
    led_state = ~led_state;
    PORTB = led_state;
}

void setup_timer_interrupt() {
    TCCR0B = 0x03;
    TIMSK0 = 0x01;
    TCNT0 = 0x00;
}
```

This should blink the LEDs on `PORTB` every time the timer interrupt occurs. Notice that the way it should be set up is by using the `ISR(...)` macro; the `__vector_...` calls you're using are deprecated and a bit more confusing.

Lastly you want to use a set of switches to hold the LED lit, if I understand your question correctly. I actually wouldn't use an external interrupt for this, just read the value of the switches using `PINK` during `ISR(TIMER0_COMP_vect)`, but we can use it if you'd like. We'll need to add the following code:

```
uint8_t switch_state;

void setup_switch_interrupt() {
    // I'm assuming this code to enable external interrupts works.
    DDRK = 0x00;
    PORTK = 0xff;
    PCMSK2 = 0xff; // set to all 1s
    PCICR = 0x04;
    PCIFR = 0x04;
}

ISR(INT0_vect) {
    switch_state = PINK;
}
```

What does this do? We will keep the state of the switches in `switch_state`, read every time the external interrupt fires (I'm guessing you have this set to happen on both 0->1 and 1->0 transitions). All that's left is to make the LED output dependent on the value of `switch_state`. We'll do this in the timer interrupt since that's where we've been toggling the LEDs so far. The new version looks like:

```
ISR(TIMER0_COMP_vect) {
    led_state = ~led_state | switch_state;
    PORTB = led_state;
}
```

And that should do it!

**Footnote:** I said earlier that using the external interrupt for reading the switches isn't really necessary. This is because you can just read the switch values during the timer interrupt using `PINK`. You can get rid of `switch_state`, `setup_switch_interrupt()`, and `ISR(INT0_vect)` and just modify the timer interrupt to be this:

```
ISR(TIMER0_COMP_vect) {
    led_state = ~led_state | PINK;
    PORTB = led_state;
}
```

That should make the program a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

So no matter what, every time your `__vector_23` executes you're cycling through the LEDs assigned to `PORTB` by incrementing `i`.  If I understand what you're trying to do what you should be doing is incrementing `i` only in `__vector_25`, when the switch is pressed.

Comment: @sneezy, I think I had it wrong when I first answered, please see my edit with some better instructions.

Comment: I don't see __vector_25 getting called.